# unix command to search count of 5XX status HTTP requests in the log

Tags: linux, http, unix, request, command

i need to write a unix command to search count of 5XX status HTTP requests in the log. Log format is like below example :

```
192.168.0.101 - - [12/Dec/2019:23:15:56 +0900] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0"
```

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal solution would be

```
$ grep "5\d{2}" somefile.log | wc -l
```

`grep` will filter the output to only the lines including the string `5XX`, where `X` is any digit character. This output is then piped to `wc -l`, which counts the number of lines produced.

However, it is possible that the string `5XX` will occur elsewhere in the log file. To account for this, you may wish to consider using a more detailed pattern in `grep`, such as

```
$ grep "HTTP/1.1\"\ 5\d{2}" somefile.log | wc -l
```

which ensures that you only match HTTP error codes and not, e.g. a future Gecko version.